# overwriting characters in a printf statement to implement snake

Tags: c

hey how to overwrite the characters in c ? Like in a printf statement.
Now i want to go back and overwrite @ with space and increment the @ on screen.
i'm trying to implement snake game.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
   printf("@");
}
```

Comment: You can't.  Try looking at Curses library.

Comment: If you're indeed OK with your snake being one-dimensional only, print `\b` to erase a character.

Comment: Use backspace (`'\b'`)?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are the [ANSI control characters](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm). Sending those will allow you to move the cursor.

e.g.:

```
printf("%c[%dA", 0x1B, 10); // move cursor 10 lines up
```